# PHP 5.6.13 SoapClient exception

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

we upgraded our php version from 5.4 to 5.6.13 and one of our webservices (soap) does not connect anymore.

We get the following output:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://someservice.com?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://someservice.com?wsdl
```

We can curl the webservice from the server and it returns 200 with the xml output. We're not passing any other parameters along with the SoapClient Call:

```
$wsdl = "https://somservice.com";
$service = new \SoapClient($wsdl . "?wsdl", $params);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can see wee what's in `$params`

Comment: sorry params was a test :) it's blank by default, I added the params as listed at the bottom of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875409/soap-php-fault-parsing-wsdl-failed-to-load-external-entity

Comment: HTTPS protocol needs to .pem file

Comment: Is openssl module enabled?

Comment: Marek, yes: OpenSSL support enabled, OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013, OpenSSL Header Version OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Comment: Disable WSDL caching: by default it is 7 days. DIfferent versions of PHP have different way of keeping it. So it may be your new PHP loads old cache and fails to parse it.

Comment: @user3713667, Disabling WSDL caching didn't help.

Comment: @mauzilla, did you get any solution?

Comment: We had to disable peer certificate checks which resolved the issue.