# SoapClient "Could not connect to host" exception with one WSDL API

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a problem with one WSDL connection with API, after moving to a new OVH VPS machine, so it's maybe some kind of strange misconfiguration.

Other WSDL that I use with SoapClient, work fine, without problems. I'm able to use `file_get_contents` on the address, but when I use `SoapClient` I gives a exception "Could not connect to host", when trying to use a procedure from that API.

Any ideas? I've tried some `stream_context` with some SSL options. What's the funniest, on the other OVH VPS is working fine.

System is Debian 8 with PHP 5.6.19 onboard.

Addresss of the WSDL is here: https://api-test.paczkawruchu.pl/WebServicePwR/WebServicePwRTest.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 2):

After consultation with WSDL provider, and checking logs on both sides, we found the anwser. It looks like PHP 5.6 have some problems, and you have to change parameters to SOAP 1.2. This resolved finally the problem. Resolution could be found here, in first comment:
[SOAP PHP fault parsing WSDL: failed to load external entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875409/soap-php-fault-parsing-wsdl-failed-to-load-external-entity)

```
// options for ssl in php 5.6.5
$opts = array(
    'ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA', 'verify_peer'=>false, 'verify_peer_name'=>false)
);
// SOAP 1.2 client
$params = array ('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'verifypeer' => false, 'verifyhost' => false, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1, "connection_timeout" => 180, 'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts) );
$oSoapClient = new SoapClient ( $url . "?WSDL", $params );
```

Comment: Or just $params = [ 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'stream_context' => stream_context_create(['ssl' => ['verify_peer'=>false]]) ]
for me...

Comment: But best : add "openssl.cafile=C:/path/to/ssl/cacert.pem" to php.ini !