# Can access WSDL only with proxy. Straight access does not work

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am constantly getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: 
>   Couldn't load from 'http://217.194.255.193:8080/work/ws/ws1.1cws?wsdl' : 
>   failed to load external entity

When I try to access WSDL in my browser I get a cyclic authorization issue as if the password doesnt fit.

I have tried to use several anonymizers, most of them act exactly as the browser itself, but one of those anonymous services worked and I managed to see the file.

Anybody has any ideas what can cause such a problem?

Here is the code I am using:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$client = new SoapClient("http://217.194.255.193:8080/work/ws/ws1.1cws?wsdl",
    array(
        'login' => 'log',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'trace' => true,
        'features' => SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE,
    )
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SOAP PHP fault parsing WSDL: failed to load external entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875409/soap-php-fault-parsing-wsdl-failed-to-load-external-entity)

Comment: Nope, none of ideas presented there helped. My problem seems to be that there is some sort of a firewall or a port/DNS issue at the server-side. I need to find a way to bypass that from my client-side as far as I have no access to the server.