# Fatal Error in Awin API - Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

Tags: php, api, magento

I have a very serious issue. I am working witht he API - https://ui.awin.com/awin/affiliate/250615?region=gb and after login into that, i found the api documentation and also php api client zip.

I then downloaded this client zip, updated all my api details and when i run - http://202.131.107.107/searchcycle/ps_client.php , I always get error as below -

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://v6.core.com.productserve.com/ProductServeService.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://v6.core.com.productserve.com/ProductServeService.wsdl" in /var/www/html/searchcycle/classes/class.php5Client.php:57 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/searchcycle/classes/class.php5Client.php(57): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://v6.core....', Array) #1 /var/www/html/searchcycle/classes/class.php5Client.php(95): Php5Client->__construct(Object(stdClass)) #2 /var/www/html/searchcycle/classes/class.ClientFactory.php(60): Php5Client::getInstance(Object(stdClass)) #3 /var/www/html/searchcycle/ps_client.php(29): ClientFactory::getClient() #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/searchcycle/classes/class.php5Client.php on line 57

Can  someone please help me in this what is missing from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Add optional SSL parameters.

#### How to solve:

```
// options for ssl in php 5.6.5
$opts = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'ciphers' => 'RC4-SHA',
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false
    )
);

// SOAP 1.2 client
$params = array(
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'verifypeer' => false,
    'verifyhost' => false,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'trace' => 1,
    'exceptions' => 1,
    'connection_timeout' => 180,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts) // Magic happens here
);

$wsdlUrl = $url . '?WSDL';
$oSoapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $params);
```

Please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875409/soap-php-fault-parsing-wsdl-failed-to-load-external-entity), you would find something useful.