# Possible compatibility issues between Exchange 2010 recent SOAP/PHP releases?

Tags: php, curl, soap, wsdl, exchange-server

Basically the project I was assigned requires me connecting to an `Exchange 2010 SP2 server` via `PHP`. I have researched several possibilities and found that **SOAP** is the most accessible approach (I could be wrong, however) and have been basing the majority of my code on this link: https://www.howtoforge.com/talking-soap-with-exchange

I got up to the following part:

```
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
```

When I tried to test it out I got an error as followed:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'SERVER ADDRESS.WSDL' : failed to load external entity "SERVER ADDRESS.WSDL" in C:\xampp\DIRECTORY:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\DIRECTORY(4): SoapClient->SoapClient('SERVER ADDRESS') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\DIRECTORY on line 4
```

Line 4 being :

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
```

I have researched the possible issues regarding this, enabled all the required things for `PHP` and researched other alternatives but I think the issue lies in the connection itself between Exchange and the code (connecting directly through the browser works fine).

To summarize my issues with a question: Is there a possible compatibility issue between the latest `PHP` and `cURL` `(currently 7.2.1. and 7.56.0 respectively)` and `Exchange 2010`?

Would it also be possible to maybe receive other suggestions on how I can tackle this issue?

Comment: Can you load "SERVER ADDRESS.WSDL" in a web browser?

Comment: @jjok: When I access it via a web browser (using Chrome if that helps) I can access the .XML file with no problems.

Comment: Potentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875409/soap-php-fault-parsing-wsdl-failed-to-load-external-entity