# How can I make SoapClient work on a server using nginx

Tags: php, nginx, soap, soap-client

I'm getting an error when using SoapClient() request. No matter which param I use, the issue remains. The server uses Nginx.

The SOAP error: http://lecturaparatodos.cl/soap.php

I check if SOAP enabled, and it's: http://lecturaparatodos.cl/soap-check.php

I chekck OpenSSL, SimpleXMLand all I think I need and it's ok: http://lecturaparatodos.cl/info.php

Here's the sample code in soap.php:

```
echo time();

$client = new \SoapClient("https://demo.l1nda.nl/api/webservice/?wsdl", 
    [
        "trace" => 1,
        "exceptions" => true, 
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'ssl' => [         
            'verify_peer' => false,        
            'verify_peer_name' => false,         
            'allow_self_signed' => true     
        ] 
    ]
);

var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

SOAP error: http://lecturaparatodos.cl/soap.php

SOAP Check: http://lecturaparatodos.cl/soap-check.php

PHP info: http://lecturaparatodos.cl/info.php

I try everything I found on Google, here and other forums. All required modules are installed, updated and nothing seems to work. If I move to another server, works perfectly. I need to keep the website on the current server that's why I ask for advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Did u already find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875409/soap-php-fault-parsing-wsdl-failed-to-load-external-entity)

Try out the "stream_context" settings.

Comment: Yes! and works but after remove `'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,` from `$params`. Why do you think this could happen? It's ok to disable cache in some situations and this should not throw error. right?

Comment: I am not into the details of SOAP but maybe the server is configured to only accept caching requests in order to reduce load?

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks, @C4pt4inC4nn4bis. I'll check with hosting support.