# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '...?wsdl' : failed to load external entity

Tags: php, xml, api, soap, wsdl

I am using a php SOAP client, my code:

```
<?php 
try{
$soapclient = new SoapClient('https://...?wsdl',
    array(
        'login'    => '...',
        'password' => '...',
    ));
$param=array('uet:testMsj1'=>'Hello');
$response =$soapclient->servisTest($param);
var_dump($response);
echo '<br><br><br>';
$array = json_decode(json_encode($response), true);
print_r($array);
 echo '<br><br><br>';
      echo '<br><br><br>';
    foreach($array as $item) {
        echo '<pre>'; var_dump($item);
    }  
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}   
?>
```

And I am getting this error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://...?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://...?wsdl"
```

I can only edit my php code because I don't have access to the API's.
Note that it was working perfectly, suddenly without changing anything in the code I started to get this error.

Comment: what is the response you got while manually trying to access the url ?

Comment: When manually trying to access the url, I get some xml code, so the problem is not with the url. Plus, this code was working perfectly like two days ago, I was getting a response, and suddenly without changing anything in the code, this happened

Comment: will this be any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875409/soap-php-fault-parsing-wsdl-failed-to-load-external-entity