# Upgrading to PHP 8.2 causes CRITICAL Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: ... failed to load external entity

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

When upgrading to PHP 8.2 we started getting the following error for one of our soap connections.

```
2023-11-08T11:25:35+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://example.com/example.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "https://example.com/example.asmx?WSDL"
```

Rolling back to PHP 8.1 resolved the issue but other areas of the system will require 8.2 soon.

We have tried various solutions online, changing the code and connection config, plus everything in this post: [SOAP PHP fault parsing WSDL: failed to load external entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875409/soap-php-fault-parsing-wsdl-failed-to-load-external-entity)

The server we are connecting to uses a self signed certificate which I believe is the root of the problem, however this is not something we can change.

This is our current code, which is working fine in PHP 8.1:

```
<?php

class MySoapClient extends \SoapClient
{

    /**
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
      $options = array (
        'local_cert' => 'client_ssl.pem',
        'passphrase' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'features' => 1,
        'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient',
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY,
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'verifypeer' => false,
        'verifyhost' => false,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'trace' => 1,
        'exceptions' => true,
        'connection_timeout' => 180,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
        array(
                'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false, 
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
            )
        ))
    );
      if (!$wsdl) {
        $wsdl = 'https://example.com/example.asmx?WSDL';
      }
      parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
    }

    /**
     * @param GetCatalog $parameters
     * @return GetCatalogResponse
     */
    public function GetCatalog(GetCatalog $parameters)
    {
      return $this->__soapCall('GetCatalog', array($parameters));
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to wrap the parameters in an extra array like `$this->__soapCall('GetCatalog', [[$parameters]];` otherwise you need to cast it to an array. `$this->__soapCall('GetCatalog', [(array)$parameters)];`. Maybe you can omit the brackets. You need to test.